# Add value to json root dynamically

Tags: javascript, json

Well, I'm so confused. I have made a json element like this:

```
var world = {"county": []};
world.county.push({name: "America", flag: "yes", countries: []});
world.county[0].countries.push({name: "Costa Rica", capital: "San Jose"});
```

This leads me to think two things:

1. I'm mixing arrays with json objects. How can I avoid using arrays in this scenario?
2. How can I add elements to the json root dynamically?

Regarding question 2, I'm facing issues because I don't know how to add elements to the root, let's say that I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
var index = 0;
var word = {};
world.index.push({name: WA});
```

So, by this way I could add elements iterating some array created previously.

Comment: "I'm mixing arrays with json objects. How can I avoid to use arrays at this scenario?" --- for what reason?

Comment: "How can I add elements to json root dinamically?" --- `world.new_root_element = 'value';`

Comment: @zerkms in order to work specifically with objects, maybe could be confused using indexes with [] instance object.attribute paradigm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with Kolink's answer. Then, for what you are doing here:

```
var index = 0;
var world = {};
world.index.push({name: "WA"});
```

It looks like you are trying to add a property to `world` with the index 0. Given you are then trying to use `.push()` it would seem you want that property to be an array, in which case you would do that like this:

```
world[index] = [];
world[index].push({name: "WA"});
```

Given that `world` started as an empty object that would create this structure:

```
{ "0" : [ {name:"WA"} ] }
```

In a general sense, to access an object property where the property is in a variable you use the `[]` array-style syntax. So:

```
world["somePropName"]
// does the same thing as
world.somePropName
// so with a variable:
var x = "somePropName";
world[x]
```

Comment: you have my idea right, `{ "0" : [ {name:"WA"} ] }` is the structure required. Thank you so much! and the rest of people too.

Comment: You're welcome. Something I forgot to mention explicitly in my answer is that you have to create the property as an array before you start adding array elements with `.push()`, but you can do it in one step as `world[index] = [ {name:"WA"} ];`

Answer (score 5):

First, let's get this out of the way: it's only JSON if it's a **string** representing a JavaScript object. What you have there is an *object literal*.

Now, as for your question, you can add elements to an object simply by using:

```
object.newProperty = value;
```

As for your wanting to avoid arrays, just use arrays. They are the correct type of object to use, and you shouldn't use anything else for that task.

Comment: +1, I completely agree. Further to what you said about JSON being a string, I'd like to explicitly note (for the OP) that JSON can represent an array, e.g., `"[1,2,3]"` is valid JSON.

Comment: @nnnnnn Since an array is just a type of object, I'm still right :p Even just `"true"` is valid JSON for a Boolean object.

Comment: @Kolink, so if I have `object.index = value` where index is a numeric var declared previously, will be converted to literal reference, right?

Comment: @manix: you cannot do so. If you have a property name in a variable, then you use it in this way: `object[index] = value;` regardless of if `object` is a javascript object or an array